# If Statement Have A String And Other String (Make To List)

Tags: javascript

Sorry i cant find the tutorial in google because i dont know the keyword...

```
var currentURL=location.href;
var str = currentURL;

      if(str == "http://web.com/blabla" || str == "http://web.com/bleble"){
        window.location = "http://web.com/ban";
      } else {
      }
```

How to make `str == "http://web.com/blabla" || str == "http://web.com/bleble"` to list ? so if i want to input some url again, i just input the url to the list. Can give me the code or link tutorial ???

Comment: [Arrays in Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are called arrays in javascript, and are declared using square brackets, like this: `var badUrls = ["http://web.com/blabla", "http://web.com/bleble"]`.

To check whether the current URL appears in the array, you can use the `.indexOf` function of the array, which will return the first position in the array where the string you provide can be found (starting with 0 for the first element), or -1 if it doesn't exist. For example, if you have an array `var arr = ["foobar", "foo", "bar", "baz"]`, and you do `arr.indexOf("foo")`, you get `1` because it's the 2nd element in the array. If instead you do `arr.indexOf("fooba")`, you will get `-1` because none of the elements in the array are `fooba` exactly. In your code, you want to redirect the user if `badUrls.indexOf(str) > -1`. You can get more information on indexOf in the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

That makes your code look like:

```
var currentURL=location.href;
var str = currentURL;
var badUrls = ["http://web.com/blabla", "http://web.com/bleble"]

if(badUrls.indexOf(str) > -1){
  window.location = "http://web.com/ban";
} else {
}
```

Comment: I would say that it's important to explain what `indexOf` actually does and what it's output means. This is a good solution but without understanding what exactly is going on here, the OP might not gain any knowledge from it.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you'll need to place all of your URL's into an array and then iterate over the array checking each item.

```
var urls = ['http://web.com/','http://web.net/','http://web.org'];
var current_url = '...';

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
  if (current_url == urls[i]){
    window.location = "http://web.com/ban";
    break; // exit the loop since we have already found a match
  }
}
```

The [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) command will terminate the loop and stop searching the array for matching URLs. Since the action you want to take needs to happen if *any* of the URLs match, it's enough for one to match in order to stop searching.

Comment: how about `urls.indexOf(current_url)`

Comment: @fuyushimoya - also a very valid solution. However I try to match my solutions to the level of programming I evaluate the asker having. I feel that this solution would be very easy to ready and understand. There's always room for improvement though - thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Well, sorry I'm just back from a gathering, a little drunken, didn't considered that, you're right here.

Comment: @fuyushimoya - all with good intentions :) Have a glass of water (or two!)

Comment: @Lix i have some error... **The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup**

Comment: @DeVoresyah - I'm not sure what you mean by that - where is the error coming from?

Answer (score 1):

window.location is a browser object, it you want the page to go to http://web.com/ban, you should use

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com/ban";
```

However, it looks like you are trying to prevent people from visiting pages using JavaScript.  This is extremely insecure, because anyone that lists your code will see which URLs you're trying to protect and immediately request them.  If they request those URLs with JavaScript disabled, or using curl, the pages will be delivered.

You should protect the pages with server side configuration.  With Apache, you can use the Allow/Deny configuration or RewriteRules.